# pandas dataframe to add the new columns and change the existing columns orient as index

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe object pandas where i want to add the new columns and change the existing columns to be the Index. Below is the dataFrame looks like.

```
 >>> df
    {'FEQoS': [0.39, 15.24, 14.91], 'Tempus': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'Voltus': [0.12, 3.22, 3.16], 'ICD PV': [0.01, 0.28, 0.28], 'CLS': [0.07, 1.96, 1.92]}
    >>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
    >>> df1
       FEQoS  Tempus  Voltus  ICD PV   CLS
    0   0.39     0.0    0.12    0.01  0.07
    1  15.24     0.0    3.22    0.28  1.96
    2  14.91     0.0    3.16    0.28  1.92
```

What i have tried that does not fulfill the requirement:

```
>>> df1.stack().to_frame().T
```

The new column i would like to ad is:

```
cols  = ['-1 day','-2 days','-3 days']
```

What is desired is as follows:

```
        -1 day  -2 days  -3 days
FEQoS     0.39    15.24    14.91
Tempus    0.00     0.00     0.00
Voltus    0.12     3.22     3.16
ICD PV    0.01     0.28     0.28
CLS       0.07     1.96     1.92
```

**I struggling to understand to use the below idea:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')
df1.columns = ['-1 day','-2 days','-3 days']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution need transpose and is possible add `index`, which is transpose to columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, index=['-1 day','-2 days','-3 days']).T
```

And for your solution with [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) need `columns`:

> **orient** : {'columns', 'index'}, default 'columns'
>
> The ''orientation'' of the data. If the keys of the passed dict should be the columns of the resulting DataFrame, pass 'columns' (default). Otherwise if the keys should be rows, pass 'index'.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index', columns = ['-1 day','-2 days','-3 days'])

print (df1)
        -1 day  -2 days  -3 days
FEQoS     0.39    15.24    14.91
Tempus    0.00     0.00     0.00
Voltus    0.12     3.22     3.16
ICD PV    0.01     0.28     0.28
CLS       0.07     1.96     1.92
```

Comment: @ jezrael , as always quick and great answer.. +1 before time will come to accept it :)